# Looking for a bibtex style with upper case Names

Tags: bibtex

Good morning to all,
I am looking for a standard author-year bib style, which capitalizes last names
plaindin does it, but it is not author-name. I tried to open the .bst file but it is in German, so I don't know whether it can be customized in order to obtain what I am looking for. Any suggestion as of a style that could look say like Chicago, but with upper case last names?

Thanks!
Francesco

Comment: Can you use `biblatex`? It is much easier to customise.

Comment: Inever used it. I write with TexMaker, that has a command for bibtex. But I'll look into it, thanks!